# Confused how to test my ranked data

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, descriptive-statistics

[image]

I am conducting an olfactory preference experiment. Basically, I have a tube with vanilla scent on one end and chocolate scent on the other. I put flies into the tube and after 10 minutes marks the position of the fly. See the diagram - C3 means strong preference for chocolate whereas V1 would be mild preference for vanilla.

I am struggling to envision how I would analyse this data. I am not sure how I would incorporate C1,C2 and C3 in order to show that a stronger preference for chocolate (C3) has a stronger effect than C1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the scent distributes linearly over the tube, you should use a one-sample t-test.

The null assumption would be 'no preference', i.e. you need to use [distance from the middle] as your continuous outcome measure (if there is no pressing reason for using segments, it would be better to measure on a fine scale, such as millimeters).

The test answers whether the distribution of fly-endpoints is significantly different from 0 (the exact middle).

Comment: I think I understand. Could you tell me how the data would be reformatted in a table. Say it looks like C3=1, C2=4, C1=0, V1=3, V2=5,V3=1. I'm thinking C1 and V1 would become 0 in the table and maybe C2 and V2 will become 1 and V3 and C3 will become 2? The reason for the segments is that my flies are tiny and skittish! This is one of my first goes in R so I am struggling a little. Thanks

Comment: Hm. In that case my previous answer is incorrect. You have [ranked data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Interval_scale), on which [you cannot use a t-test](https://sciencing.com/can-use-ttest-ranked-data-12010046.html). You might need the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) but that is designed for ordinal data. Sorry, it turns out this one beats me.

Comment: ah back to the drawing board! No problem, thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider what the distribution of fly locations after ten minutes would have been if there were no scents at either end - i.e. your null hypothesis. Would it be normal, with most flies staying in the middle and a small number ending up at either end? Or do flies wander around a lot - maybe you would have a uniform distribution?

Either way, you can then use a chi-square test (or Fisher's exact test assuming your sample size is small?) to check the deviation of the measured distribution of fly locations from the null distribution, and thus infer a preference for one or other of the scents.